# Cannot do normal select in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I try to do normal select on database, like `select * from xxx limit 0,30`.

But I get this message : `ERROR 29 (HY000): File 'tablename.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13)`

I try to search the file on mysql datafile folder, and I find it. How can this happen.

Comment: Did you mess with your filesystem somehow? It could be possible that your file is corrupted. Does `show tables;` tell you that `tablename` is still there?

Comment: i don't know, previous developer give me this problem. and i just found this problem.

Comment: `Errorcode: 13` normally means Permission Denied. Check the permissions of the MYD-file and the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access the database using a tool like PhpMyAdmin?

According to this [site](http://www.articlesnatch.com/Article/Resolving-Error-29-In-Mysql-Database/788529) a full repair should solve it:

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases --auto-repair -ucojjohealth -p
```

If that doesn't solve it:

> While the above command repairs
>   corrupted databases in most cases,
>   there is a possibility of getting a
>   new error message after this command:
>
> error: File '../diaendomet/users.MYD'
>   not found (Errcode: 2)
>
> If you encounter the above error
>   message, then your database has been
>   corrupted badly. To repair your
>   database in such situations, you will
>   need to use third-party MySQL Database
>   Recovery tools. MySQL Recovery
>   utilities provide advanced, complete,
>   and risk-free database repair
>   applications that repair damaged MySQL
>   database while maintaining the
>   intactness of data. These tools employ
>   high-end scanning mechanisms to
>   comprehensively repair the corrupted
>   MySQL databases. With to-the-point
>   documentation, the tools serve as
>   self-explanatory and repair-centric
>   tools.
>
> Read more:
>   http://www.articlesnatch.com/Article/Resolving-Error-29-In-Mysql-Database/788529#ixzz1OlEpu62A

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the table is corrupt or lost the .MYD file.

Try to repair the table if it is corrupt it can bring back the file - please refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repair-table.html

> repair table tablename

Answer (score 0):

Just as an outside chance, are you using different cased name in your `select` from your `create` statement.

```
select * from banana;
```

is different on case sensitive file systems (ie linux) to:

```
select * from BANANA;
```

There is a `mysql.cnf` option that turns this off.