# './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying to do a fresh install of Mac OSX LAMP and running the command

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

I have inputting the root password and I have to now input a new password when I'm hit with this error, has anyone got any experience with this?

```
Re-enter new password:
 ... Failed! Error: File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Comment: Did you try a db repair like suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289364/5687152 ?

Comment: I did , I think there was a corruption in the install as I have taken over this machine from an ex employee , I have now removed SQL and brew Install and it works now

Answer (score 8):

Please retry to completely remove mysql by executing:

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

And then restart your computer to make sure that all the processes have been killed.

Then execute these commands to install MySQL:

```
brew update
brew install mysql
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --verbose --user='<your-username>' --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
mysql.server start
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a corruption within the install and decided to delete and use brew to install and all is now well! Follow these steps

Open a terminal window
Use mysqldump to backup your databases to text files!
Stop the database server

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

Then installed via Brew

```
brew install mysql
```

Comment: I have tried all the above steps my in Mac OS 10.13 still comes up with same error when i am trying to set the root password